# Full Site Editing Non-editble global styles?

Tags: css, block-editor, full-site-editing

Working my way through learning FSE, I'm using this [this article](https://fullsiteediting.com/lessons/global-styles/) and wondered what to do for global styles you **don't** want user control over?

Previous this would be controlled via `style.css` however, it seems split apart as you have styles for individual blocks as well as layout/typography etc called via the `theme.json`

Have I missed something or is there a json setting or style sheet that can be called within the editor as well as front end but is also not customisable via the theme editor?

Comment: this isn't a discussion forum so you can't ask open questions or advice, that's offtopic. You can ask specific questions though, and this is very close to to that. Don't ask for best practices, directly ask how to do it instead. Remember, you need to be able to mark a single answer as the correct answer for all people with this question, not the most helpful advice. I've tried to edit your question to avoid this problem

Comment: My apologies, thank you.